# How to implement pattern matching in java and avoid instanceof?

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns, polymorphism, instanceof

At the moment I don't know how to avoid code smells in my piece of code.
I've tried several patterns (Strategy, Visitor) and they didn't provide a clean and maintainable solution. Here is an example of my code for strategy pattern:

```
public interface Strategy {
  <T> T foo(FirstParam firstParam, SecondParam secondParam);
}

public class StrategyOne implements Strategy {
  FirstReturnType foo(FirstParam firstParam, SecondParam secondParam);
}

public class StrategyTwo implements Strategy {
  SecondReturnType foo(FirstParam firstParam, SecondParam secondParam);
}

@Setter
public class Context {
    private Strategy strategy;
    public void execute(FirstParam firstParam, SecondParam secondParam) {
        if (strategy != null) {
            strategy.fo(firstParam, secondParam);
        }
    }
}
```

And there is a example of objects.

```
public abstract class Action {
 abstract void bar();
} 

public class ActionOne extends Action {
  void bar() {}
}

public class ActionTwo extends Action {
  void bar() {}
}
```

And I want to make this piece of code cleaner

```
public class ActionExecutor {
   private Context context;
   private FirstParam firstParam;
   private SecondParam secondParam;
   public ActionExecutor(FirstParam firstParam, SecondParam secondParam) {
    this.context = new Context();
    this.firstParam = firstParam;
    this.secondParam = secondParam;
   }

  public void doSmth(Item item) {
    Action action = item.getAction();
    if(action instanceof ActionOne) {
     context.setStrategy(new StrategyOne());
    }
    if(action instanceof ActionTwo) {
     context.setStrategy(new StrategyTwo());
    }
    context.execute(firstParam, secondParam);
  }
}
```

The idea is to perform a specific action for a specific object type. But I don't know how to avoid the usage of instanceof in this situation.

Comment: This guy knows Design Patterns & Generics but not enough to use them correctly. What's the point of using Generics when you're seggregating them into `FirstReturnType` and `SecondReturnType` . Have a look at Strategy Pattern, your ActionExecutor should become that. You should program to interfaces not to classes.

Comment: Actually, ```Action Executor``` is a business logic class and cannot be part of Strategy Pattern. And I use generics because these methods have different return types.

Comment: Maybe you could improve your question by 1) explaining why you do not like to use the instanceof 2) Mention that you cannot modify the Action classes

Comment: I would avoid instanceof because it is not a scalable and clear solution.
In case of increasing amount of ```Action``` types I should add another ```if (action instanceof NewType)``` and that's messy.

Comment: @privalou You receive an action, and based on what the action is, you need to set the context. It would make sense for the action itself to be able to set the context.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways top of my head.

```
public abstract class Action {
 public Strategy strategy;
 abstract void bar();
} 

public class ActionOne extends Action {
  void bar() {}
   // set strategy here,  possibly
}

public class ActionTwo extends Action {
  void bar() {}
}

public void doSmth(Item item) {
    Action action = item.getAction();
    action.strategy.execute(firstParam, secondParam);
  }
```

Second way, have an enum in all your actions and force it by declaring it as a parameter in your abstract class constructor. Then just use switch in instead of instanceof

Comment: I guess that bringing Strategy to Action will increase Coupling. And that's what I'm trying to avoid in my code.
This is why I refused from the Visitor Pattern because that approach would make my ```Action``` class way too specific and heavy.

Comment: Not really, it's just an interface not a strong type so it's not tight coupling anyway.

Comment: Well, the thing is, that I cannot modify Action class, because it is located at another module and I am just its consumer.
I might create a new abstract class with StrategyPattern inside, but it will force me to make a cast an incoming object to my new class. But I hope that won't be a problem :)

Comment: could you tell how can I set elegantly to each ```Action``` specific Strategy?

Answer (score 2):

Could be something like this:

```
   public void doSmth(Item item) {

    Action action = item.getAction();

    Map<String,Strategy> strategies = new HashMap<>();
    strategies.put(ActionOne.getClass().getSimpleName(),new StrategyOne());
    strategies.put(ActionTwo.getClass().getSimpleName(),new StrategyTwo());
    ..
    strategies.put(ActionHundred.getClass().getSimpleName(),new StrategyHundred());

    if(strategies.containsKey(action.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
     context.setStrategy(strategies.get(action.getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }
    context.execute(firstParam, secondParam);  }
```

Comment: I don't think that it worths to fulfill map at that method. But I didn't catch the idea where I can do that.

Comment: why not?  if you have just 2-3 strategy types then just keep 'instanceOf', if more - definitely need some mapping, as in my sample.

Comment: Because it doesn't look like an optimal solution to me. But I will try similar approach :)

Comment: Here is the same problem as in original solution using instanceof. If a new action type is added there will not be a compile time error. Failure to add check for new action will only be noticed at runtime.

Comment: Compiler error for missing case? No thats not possible without external tools.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a textbook use case for the [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.  You can use the same code you have now (or the Map example in another answer), but put it in a factory - then it's purpose-specific and decoupled from the code that uses it.

Something like this.

```
public class StrategyFactory {

    public static Stategy getStrategy(Action action) {
        if(action instanceof ActionOne) {
            return new StrategyOne();
        } else if(action instanceof ActionTwo) {
            return new StrategyTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, something like this.

```
Action action = item.getAction();
action.setStrategy(StrategyFactory.getStrategy(action));
```

There's another example here: https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-strategy-and-factory-patterns

Comment: Factory Method is never static. To my knowledge, there is no static method in any GoF pattern.

Comment: @jaco0646 Static factory methods are a thing. Joshua Bloch recommends using them in place of constructors in his book Effective Java. Is it a GoF pattern? Doesn't matter, it's still a solution.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, I agree with all of that. My point is, Factory Method and Static Factory Method are two entirely separate patterns. Unfortunately the two are often conflated due to their names. This answer makes a statement about Factory Method, but then implements Static Factory Method. That's confusing.